# Forcing Express Migration Tool to Sync Security

Tags: security, migration, express-migration-tool

Is there a way to force the Express Migration Tool (v1.0 in my case*) to re-syncronize security items. It seems that this is a known issue that it will only sync security users and roles once. ([See this KB article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/583017) which indicates this is still an issue in v2.0).

I'm assuming it writes some sort of marker somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - it looks like everything is stored in a SQLite db called `migration.db` which is in the directory where the Migration Tool was run from. I renamed this, had to re-specify all my paths & connection strings and it migrated the users.

Comment: Please mark your answer as "answered", thanks :-)

Comment: I will when I can. Still have 11h until I can